# Need to repeat code 30 times

Tags: vba, excel

this is my code and I want to re-execute it so that the next column has the exact same code repeated on it. That is, `D:28` moves to `E:28` and range `E:110:I120` moves  to `F110:J120`. I am having trouble finding a loop that does this, can anyone please help. My code is,

```
Sub Rebuild() 
tonnes = Range("D28").Value
If tonnes > 2600000 Then

Range("E110:I120").Select
Selection.Copy

Range("E18:I28").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste

Else:

Range("E18:I28").Interior.Color = xlNone
Range("E18:I18") = ""
Range("E19:I19") = ""
Range("E20:I20") = 0
Range("E21:I21") = 2.4
Range("E22:I22") = "=E21+E20"
Range("E23:I23") = "=24 - E22"
Range("E24:I24") = "=100 * E23 / 24"
Range("E25:I25") = 3000
Range("E26:I26") = "=E25 * E23"
Range("E27:I27") = "=E26"
Range("E28:I28") = "=D28 + 27"

End If
End Sub
```

Comment: do you want the cell references in your formulas to change or be the same after they are copied?  does E25*E23 become F25*F23?

Comment: Yeah I want them all to changeso that the code is repeated for the next column for the 30 columns in the sheet

Comment: The only code that I want to stay the same is the range I am copying which is E110:I120

Comment: In your title you say you want something repeated 30 times. What part do you want repeated 30 times.

Comment: So this code is copying and pasting a range if the value in D28 is greater than 2600000 and I am happy with that. But I want it to go for the whole workbook executing next starting with E28 if thats > 2600000 then execute the same thing ive copied but into the next column over etc

Comment: Is your destination range correct?  E110:I120 is 5 columns wide.  Your destination range is F110:J120 which is over writing some of the information you just copied.....Are you really just trying to copy 1 column and move everything to the right by 1 column and pasted the copied column back in.

Comment: Is this a ![good before image](http://i.imgur.com/FRRBvSD.png?1) and this an ![after image](http://i.imgur.com/IKsk1zn.png?1) of what you are trying to achieve just in terms of copying?

Comment: My destination range is E118:E128

Comment: What I am trying to achieve is to have an excel sheet that auto updates for the maintenance of a crusher. So when the tonnes is greater than 2600000 will need to paste the maintenance block. If not want to paste the normal formatting of the cells. 

The first tonnes to be checked is in D28, then next will be in E28, so if D28 is not at the tonnes were maintenance is required will check if at E28 if it is all the way up to cell AH28.

Comment: I can do this manually but its a spreadsheet monthly and its very time consuming as I have to update it regularly

Comment: I know Jeeped will hate this but I am having a really hard time visualizing what you are trying to achieve.  Is it possible for you to post a partial screen shot of your spread sheet showing initial set up, and then another one showing what you want after the copy has been done once then when it has been done twice.  I am not worried about the formulas just yet as we can take care of those once we see how the data is being moved.

Comment: @forwarded

[This is what I have][1]


[and this is what I want][2]


  [1]: http://i.stack.imgur.com/ZwtOa.png
  [2]: http://i.stack.imgur.com/NU5qQ.png

Need that block to move so that it executes when cumtonnes>26000000

Answer (score 0):

```
Option Explicit

Sub Rebuild()

Dim cumtonnes As Long

'you initially had tonnes as the variable name, but I was not sure if this was a typo or not.
cumtonnes = Range("D28").Value

If cumtonnes > 2600000 Then

    Range("E110:I120").Copy Range("F110:J120")

    Range("D28").Copy Range("E28")

Else:

    Range("E18:I28").Interior.Color = xlNone
    Range("E18:I18") = ""
    Range("E19:I19") = ""
    Range("E20:I20") = 0
    Range("E21:I21") = 2.4
    Range("E22:I22") = "=E21+E20"
    Range("E23:I23") = "=24 - E22"
    Range("E24:I24") = "=100 * E23 / 24"
    Range("E25:I25") = 3000
    Range("E26:I26") = "=E25 * E23"
    Range("E27:I27") = "=E26"
    Range("E28:I28") = "=D28 + 27"

End If
End Sub
```

So I adjusted the part that will do the copy and paste of the cells.  I did not add in any loop currently as I did not know what you wanted repeated 30 times.

Comment: `tonnes` is the standard spelling of metric tons: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tonne

Comment: @JohnColeman I use tonnes all the time where I work.  in the original post there was tonnes as a variable and cumtonnes as a variable.  I made an assumption that he wanted both the same  I just happened to change it in the wrong direction.

Comment: I see -- the original typo must have been removed in subsequent edits.